# Append two tables from SQLite database before query using R

Tags: r, sqlite, dbplyr

I have an SQLite database with several large tables containing the same variables. Usually I establish a connection and make a query (using dbplyr) like this:

```
database <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "/database.sqlite")

table_1 <- tbl(database, "datatable_1")
table_2 <- tbl(database, "datatable_2")

table_1_final <- table_1 %>% filter(id < 1000) %<% collect()
table_2_final <- table_2 %>% filter(id < 1000) %<% collect()
```

Instead of doing

```
table_final <- bind_rows(table_1_final, table_2_final)
```

I would like to append the two tables in a first step so that I can make a query like this

```
table_final <- table %>% filter(id < 1000) %>% collect()
```

where `table` already refers to an the appended tables `datatable_1` and `datatable_2` from the SQLite database.

**However** I do not want to create the appended table permanently inside the database and I do not want to load them into memory (too big).

(How) can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

you can use  `union_all` for this:

Example Code:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
data("mtcars")

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
copy_to(con, mtcars[1,], "mtcars1")
copy_to(con, mtcars[2,], "mtcars2")

mtcars1 <- tbl(con, "mtcars1")
mtcars2 <- tbl(con, "mtcars2")

mt_combined <- union_all(mtcars1,mtcars2)

mt_combined <- collect(mt_combined)
```

This performs the `UNION` SQL Statement, if both tables are from the same Databes connection.